# how to troubleshoot dockerfile when application crash/fail in the container?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

If the application fails in the docker container you would not be able to troubleshoot what happened. Please propose a solution to that

Comment: You could start the container in interactive mode -it

Comment: Have you check your  logs? `docker logs <<container>>`

Answer (score 1):

```
docker ps -a
```

This will list all the containers including those who have already existed (for whatever reason)

Then you can copy the process id of the container of your interest and:

```
docker logs <pid of container that has failed>
```

Another interesting command is:

```
docker inspect <pid of container that has failed>
```

It returns a big json - you can check some sections there, like memory settings, "State" (if the process was OOM killed and so forth)